# Click on a span, make it disappear and make something else appear

Tags: jquery, visibility

I have a php code:

```
<div class="spacermenu">
                <span>Just a write</span>
                <div class="spacerhidden">
                        <input type"text" class="spacetext"> <img class="spacetext" src="images/delete.png">
                </div>
</div>
```

and a jquery script

```
$(".spacermenu span").click(function () {
    $(this).css("display","none");
    $(??????).css("display","block");
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, when I click on "Just a write", make that span disappear (done) and make the .spacerhidden div appear. My guessing was using a selector like ".spacermenu .spacerhidden", but that shows ALL the .spacerhidden divs and not the one i clicked in.

What I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance.

at everyone so far: isn't "next" a bit unprecise, even if it works atm? Can't I select that precise element?

Comment: How would `next` be `unprecise`?

Comment: (offtopic) you should close your `img` tags!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `next` method.

```
$(".spacermenu span").click(function () {
    $(this).hide().next('.spacerhidden').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(".spacermenu span").click(function () {
    $(this).css("display","none");
    $(this).next().css("display","block");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `next`

```
$(".spacermenu span").click(function () {
    $(this).next('.spacerhidden').css("display","block");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wYPtR/1/)